# Как узнать значение select у всх элементов определенного класса на странице?

Tags: html, jquery

У меня есть динамическая форма. Выбор селект с одинаковым классом, но разными идентификаторами

```
$('.select_input');
```

Как узнать все выбранные значения в select - элементов данного класса?
Вот так выводит только 1 элемент `var select = $('select.select_input');`

Потом, можно как-то, узнав значение элмента - узнать id самого селекта select'a ?
Например, первый элемент `class = "select_input" id = "30"`,
второй тогда `class = "select_input" id = "31"`
и т.д. (id = 32,33,34..)
Можно ведь узнать все эти id, зная только класс ?

UPD
Таким циклом получаю элементы

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
$.each($('select.select_input'), function (index, value) {
        console.log(value);
    });
```

Таким образом получаю выбранные select

```
 $.each($('select.select_input'), function (index, value) {
        values = value.value;
        console.log(values);
    });
```

Теперь мне нужно склеить значение select`a - 3 и 5 , и из значения id "достать" последнюю цифру - из id="types_val0" нужен 0 .

ПОлучается на выходе мне нужно, по скрину - #31 и #51 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

p.s.

```
$.each($('select.select_input'), function (index, value) {
        values = value.name;
        console.log(values);
    });
```

- выводит почему-то types_val , хотя должно по идее  types_val0 / types_val1

Comment: [.map](http://api.jquery.com/map/)

Answer (score 1):

Лучше как то поудобнее организовать связь между данными, сейчас это просто дремучий лес. Да и смысл вопроса весьма смутен. Но, из того что понял вот пример:

```
$('.select_input').each(function(){
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    id = id[id.length-1];
    console.log(id + '' +  $(this).val());
})
```